# C# WPF not capable to draw heatmaps on 3D Meshes

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, 3d, polygon

Hi a long time ago i used this code in a Windows Form App to draw a gradient in a single triangle, which could later be used to generate a color based heatmap over a 3D Mesh:

```
PathGradientBrush gradientBrush = new PathGradientBrush(points);
Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green };
gradientBrush.CenterColor = Color.ToARGB(85,85,85);
gradientBrush.SurroundColors = colors;
surface.FillPolygon(gradientBrush, points);
```

I was able to draw a gradient like this from the corners of the triangle, which faded seamlessly into the middle of it. By placing many triangles together i could generate a colormap on my 3D mesh which was seamless, no sharp borders.

However there is not PathGradientBrush in WPF anymore. How can I generate a colormap like that between three points with only the limited linear and radial brushes? Are there any other ways to generate the same result?

Comment: Have you seen the LinearGradientBrush Class?

Comment: Yes but you can't use it with that. It only makes a brush from one point to another, not between three points.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is more base for the GUI reach application and there are many available library for same

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx